# How can I locate the source of this exhaust rattle?

Tags: exhaust, leak, infiniti, g35

'04 Infiniti G35.  [**Recording of sound I'm hearing**](https://streamable.com/abef5).  The best example is at 0:39 onward.  Heard best with headphones.

Firstly: I'm aware I have an exhaust leak.  That part, I can hear all the time, this rattle is on top of it.

When I last had it in the shop, I was told that the flexpipe was old.  Personally, I didn't think it looked too bad, there are a couple of very small, very slightly frayed areas, but that's it.  I decided to live with it for now.

It only occurs when the engine is up to temp, and under load between 1500 and 2500 RPM.

So far, I have:

- tightened some loose heat shields with hose clamps
- fastened hose clamps between an exhaust brace and the cats (previously attached to the cats with a welded-on bracket that had corroded)

No difference so far.

How do I find the source?  I would just run it and observe where exhaust is escaping, but it only occurs under load.

**UPDATE**

Replaced the Y-pipe, sound is gone

Comment: Are you *sure* it's an exhaust rattle? It only happens under acceleration. It could very well be some light pinging/detonation going on. It's really hard to tell from the audio. I had to turn the volume up extensively to even hear the noise you're talking about. If it is an exhaust rattle, you should be able to lightly tap your exhaust system with a rubber mallet to figure out where it's at. The vibrations from the hammer should help you reproduce the noise and locate it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the audio, I don't have any good recording gear.  I can understand how it might sound like pinging from that audio, but I can open my door and hear the sound emanating from underneath, and my ECU isn't throwing any codes.

Comment: Fair enough, just making sure. Still, you should be able to tap on your exhaust system lightly to help find the location of the rattle.

Comment: If you still have a problem locating it by way of @Paulster2 good suggestion, It might be possible that it is coming from inside the catalytic converter itself.

Comment: ah-ah?  https://streamable.com/2r31d  That third part where I'm tapping is the flexpipe in the y-pipe.